# How to write $e^{\sum_{j=1}^{j=k} \frac{z^j}{j}}$ to the form $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}b_mz^{m}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to write $e^{\sum_{j=1}^{j=k} \frac{z^j}{j}}$ to the form $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}b_mz^{m}$?

I am trying to use the power series of $e^{z}$, which gives me $e^{\sum_{j=1}^{j=k} \frac{z^j}{j}}= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{j=1}^{j=k} \frac{z^j}{j})^m$, what is next?

Comment: You can expand $\left(\sum_{j =1}^k \frac{z^j}{j}\right)^m$ using the Multinomial theorem (a generalization of the binomial theorem).

Comment: It's not gonna be pleasant, though.

Comment: Also, don't forget the $\frac{1}{m!}$ part.

Comment: We know that $b_0=b_1=b_2=\cdots b_k=1$.

Comment: I do not really think that expanding it will give me the form I desired since I need to contract all the terms to be $z^{m}$@ThomasAndrews